# Pandas - Convert date to datetime format

Tags: pandas

I have column that has date value. I am trying to convert it to date time format. Given below is my dataset and what I have tried thus far.

```
date
2019-01-02
2019-01-03
```

I have converted it into date time as below:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

However it still shows in yyyy-mm-dd format. I am trying to get it to "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS" format

Expected output:

```
2019-01-02 00:00:00
2019-01-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Do you just need the representation changed? Because your timestamps above are equal to the ones below, you can verify with `df.date.dt.time`

Comment: @user3483203, I am trying to achieve that values shows below. Even though I have done `pd.to_datetime ()` it still does not show the time component

Comment: After using pd.to_datetime can you print the dtypes of your df?

Comment: @Datanovice sorry forgot to mention the dtypes. It is `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: It is already stored as `datetime` internally. If you want that format you can do `df.date.dt.strftime(format='%y-%m-%d %hh24:%MM:%ss')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I get an error `ValueError: time data '2019-01-02' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %HH24:%MM:%SS' (match)`

Comment: This is just a display issue. It will only display the timepart it's different than `'00:00:00'` for at least one value. But it's there in the underlying data.

Comment: ^ as ALolz said, if you try `pd.to_datetime(df.date + pd.to_timedelta("00:00:01"))` this will show the time value. If you just need it visible try `dt.strftime("%d-%m-%y")` but then the column becomes a string instead of datetime